# Identify when UIView is dragged on top of a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a draggable view (UIImageView) which I control its positioning and dragging using the UIPanGestureRecognizer and this method:

```
- (void)imageDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)gesture.view;
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:img];
    img.center = CGPointMake(img.center.x + translation.x,
                           img.center.y + translation.y);
    // reset translation
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:img];
}
```

Other than the draggable view, I also have a UICollectionView, built of course by UICollectionViewCells. What Im trying to do, is to identify when my draggable view is dragged on top of one of the collection view cells.

I thought of adding a boolean to the imageDragged method, to know when the view is currently being dragged, but I wasn't able to figure out how to know when my dragged touch is on top of a collection view cell. The UICollectionView has the didSelect delegate method, but that doesn't really help me if my tap didn't occur on the cells, but on my draggable view.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a tidier way, but perhaps you can get the point of the tap and/or some points on the corners of the dragged UIView and then use CGRectContainsPoint to see if those points are within the rect of the collection view cell.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I decided to go in the direction you said, and its working. I am not sure if this is the best solution, but definitely worth a vote up for now.

Comment: Ill add the snippet of the solution I did, and choose your answer.

Comment: Depending on how precisely you are defining the positions of the items in your collection view, you might be able to calculate the view under the dragged view in constant time, rather than searching each view in turn and getting it in linear time.

Answer (score 2):

I put this snippet inside the imageDropped method to achieve what I wanted (thanks to Martin's help):

```
CGPoint tapCoordinates = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
NSArray * visibleCells = [self.collectionView visibleCells];
for(UICollectionViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
    CGRect frame = [self.collectionView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(frame, tapCoordinates)) {
        NSLOG(@"Success");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done, and way to credit the person who gave you direction.

Comment: Note: CGRectContainsPoint will check whether the points are within the frame or not. It will not check equal to the endpoint. Eg. Let's say if both the parameters end points are 100 then CGRectContainsPoint will return false. In the above code snippet tapCoordinates y point should be < 100.